# How to determine altitude when altimeters fail?

Tags: altitude, amateur-rocketry, model-rocketry

Specifically for high altitude amateur rocketry, how is altitude determined when you get too high(too low pressure) for barometric altimeters to work? I heard about GPS, however, COCOM limitations seem to make this impossible.

Comment: The discussion in the [Raspberry Pi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=67006&p=490220) is actually quite helpful. It mentions the [Adafruit Ultimate GPS](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps) which states the 515 m/s velocity limit. While the [PDFs](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/GlobalTop-FGPMMOPA6H-Datasheet-V0A.pdf) state 18,000 meter altitude limit, the [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6A99O-mCZSM) (found [here](https://www.adafruit.com/products/746)) states 50 kilometers.

Comment: There is [additional discussion in [community.balloonchallenge.org](http://community.balloonchallenge.org/t/what-is-the-maximum-altitude-of-typical-gps-module/236/7) of GPS units which work at high-altitude, but at low speed. These are high altitude balloon applications. Also in this post in [Ars Technica Openforum](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=23945389&sid=b8f4cc25112b5c17f22419a67b9a83ba#p23945389) See also [Current situation with CoCom regulations and GPS receivers for balloons and cubesats](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14687/12102)

Comment: Measuring distance and doppler speed relative to a radio control ground station as well as direction and compute altitude using these values?

Comment: A serious amateur can build their own, unrestricted, GPS receiver or hack an off the shelf module to bypass the restrictions.

Comment: @Dragongeek references to hacking of firmware at the end of [this post](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14687/12102) and in comments below [this post](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15113/12102). "partial hacking" discussed in [this post](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25814/12102).