# Are software defined GNSS (GPS) receivers legal under ITAR and other export regulations?

Tags: gps, gnss, itar, open-source

With the latest update to [ITAR rules](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2016-24225/p-271), it looks like covered GNSS receivers are defined as follows:

> (2) Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS) receiving equipment, as
> follows:
>
> (i) GNSS receiving equipment specially designed for military
> applications (MT if designed or modified for airborne applications and
> capable of providing navigation information at speeds in excess of 600
> m/s);
>
> (ii) Global Positioning System (GPS) receiving equipment specially
> designed for encryption or decryption (e.g., Y-Code, M-Code) of GPS
> precise positioning service (PPS) signals (MT if designed or modified
> for airborne applications);
>
> (iii) GNSS receiving equipment specially designed for use with an
> antenna described in Category XI(c)(10) (MT if designed or modified
> for airborne applications); or
>
> (iv) GNSS receiving equipment specially designed for use with rockets,
> missiles, SLVs, drones, or unmanned air vehicle systems capable of
> delivering at least a 500 kg payload to a range of at least 300 km
> (MT);

<sup><sub>NB: MT is an abbreviation for Missile Technology (Control Regime)</sub></sup>

Do open source software defined GPS receivers fall under these laws? In particular, point 2.i is quite worrying: while they are probably not specifically designed for airborne applications, I think they probably **are** capable of working airborne, and they can certainly produce a position fix at speeds in excess of 600 m/s.

Comment: searching the site for [GPS firmware](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12102+gps+firmware) provides some insight, it's possible that a GPS chip for "civilian use" could have its firmware user-modified/updated so that it could work beyond certain speed and altitude limits, cf. references to [ladyada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limor_Fried) in [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25814/12102) and [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15109/12102) and [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14687/12102).

Comment: worth noting that ITAR/EAR does not make covered items illegal to build or possess.  It governs the *export* of said items (though the definition of "export" is fraught with peril if you decide you want to toe that line -- e.g., conversations can be considered "exports")

Comment: Yes open source should be legal and stand above any other laws. See here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41212/trade-restrictions-on-open-source-software